# bash: history -a not writing unless HISTFILE already has text

Tags: bash, shell, history

#### Problem statement

I've been following numerous examples for doing creative things with bash history along the lines of:

```
# simplified example
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a; history -c; history -r'
```

... but it seemed to work intermittently.  If the history file already exists with previous history then everything is fine.

#### Other relevant info

- bash versions: 3.2.51, 4.1.2, and 4.2.45

  - 4.2.x doesn't appear to have this problem, but it's a non-default install
- OS: Linux & Solaris
- home dir is NFS mounted

#### Diagnostic steps

I got rid of my `.bashrc` & set my `.bash_profile` to:

```
HISTFILE=$HOME/.bash_history.test
```

I would then start a login shell (eg, ssh to another machine) & do something like the following:

```
~ cat .bash_history.test
cat: .bash_history.test: No such file or directory
~ history
    1  cat .bash_history.test
    2  history
~ history -a
~ !-3
cat .bash_history.test
cat: .bash_history.test: No such file or directory
```

The history file won't get appended to by `history -a` under the following circumstances:

- The file doesn't already exist
- The file is empty or only contains newlines; even whitespace will make it work

... however, when the shell exits it *does* create it.  Thereafter, `history -a` works as expected ... except when `PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r"`.  When I had that set, even exiting the shell didn't create the history file (unless I ran `exec bash` first).

I then tried with a non-standard install of bash (4.2.x) and the problem didn't manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This mailing list thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2010-08/msg00071.html) appears to explain away these problems; quoting from the 2nd msg:

> The current code in bashhist.c:maybe_append_history() (which has
>   existed for at least 15 years) seems to not handle the case where the
>   number of history lines in the current session is equal to the number
>   of history list entries.  That is, the code won't append new lines if
>   it doesn't think there were any lines read from the history file when
>   the shell started.  That seems wrong, and I've attached a patch that
>   fixes it. However, the code has existed in its current form for so
>   long that I'm wondering whether or not there is some other reason for
>   it.
>
> (Chet Ramey, GNU bash mailing list)

Furthermore, the [changelog](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/diff/CWRU/changelog?id=495aee441b75276e38c75694ccb455bb6463fdb9) for 4.2 has the following text:

```
+                  8/13
+                  ----
+bashhist.c
+   - in maybe_append_history, change check for history_lines_this_session
+     so that we append the lines to the file if it's equal to the value
+     returned by where_history().  This means that without this change,
+     the history won't be appended if all the lines in the history list
+     were added in the current session since the last time the history
+     file was read or written.  Fixes bug reported by Bruce Korb
+     <bruce.korb@gmail.com>

(git.savannah.gnu.org, bash git repo)
```

Obviously we need to get a newer version of bash installed to resolve this problem.

Hopefully this helps someone else down the road.